# IEX Cloud: How to get the historical daily prices of a stock from a certain date to the current date

Tags: javascript, api, finance

I'm just curious how I would go about getting all the historical prices of a stock from a specific date (e.g. 2019-08-04) to the current date. I've tried many different cases under the [Historical Prices](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#historical-prices) section of the docs but I can't seem to get the functionality I'm looking for.

I would imagine this is the endpoint it would be under I just don't know how to get the desired functionality:

[https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{symbol}/chart/](https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/%7Bsymbol%7D/chart/)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest to use [Time Series endpoint](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#time-series). It's been a while since I've used IEX so the exact URL I provide may not be the correct format, but it should be along the same lines.

`/time-series/HISTORICAL_PRICES/{company}?from={date1}&to={currentdate}`

to current date is not necessary but just included for general usage if you want to find historical prices for another window.